# Regexp for Word similarity "n letter difference"

Tags: java, sql, regex, mariadb

Assume i have a word like this; **mert** . I want to to search for all 1 letter difference combinations for that word. ***aert, ert, meat,mmert, merst,merts*** etc. are all applicable. So my regular expression is like

```
[a-z]{0,2}ert OR m[a-z]{0,2}rt OR me[a-z]{0,2}t OR mer[a-z]{0,2}
```

So for n letter difference, i just replace 2 with n-1 and you **can'T** get all combinations.

*My question is this; Is there any shorter way of writing this regexp?*

Thanks

Comment: Your regex doesn't work for all `n` letter differences larger than 1. For example, if `n=2`, `mierts` (with 2 inserts `m[i]ert[s]`) wouldn't match with your regex. Or is this intended, and you're only looking for `n`-sized substring inserts instead of a [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) of `n`?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks for pointing it out. Also, levenshtein distance looks promising. It will be hard to apply that in database functions but  it is a good start. Do you have any suggestion for regex?

Comment: I'm not sure regex is the way to go with a variable `n` Levenshtein distance. The regex would be pretty big, and will probably need backtracking to know the substring-sizes you've already matched for `n>1`.. Since MariaDB is based on MySQL iIrc, perhaps searching for "Levenshtein distance MySQL function" might give some helpful search results to get started?

Comment: There are fuzzy matching features in some regex libraries (e.g. TRE, PyPi regex), but not the PCRE library used in MariaDB.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this solution, I have test this code below. It seems to work.

```
/**
 * Then function will return list of the words matched with nth_difference
 *
 * @param pattern search pattern
 * @param data input data
 * @param nth_difference difference
 * @return
 */
static List<String> getNthDifferenceWords(String pattern, String[] data, int nth_difference) {
    Map<Character, Integer> frequencyTable = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> matchedWords = new ArrayList<>();
    //Code complexity : O(n)
    for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length(); ++i) {
        frequencyTable.put(pattern.charAt(i), 1);
    }
    //Code complexity : O(m) where m is size of entire input;
    for (String input : data) {
        int matchCounter = 0;
        for (int j=0; j<input.length(); ++j){
            if(frequencyTable.containsKey(input.charAt(j))){
                ++matchCounter;
            }
        }
        //System.out.println("matched=" + matchCounter);
        if(input.length() <= pattern.length() && (matchCounter == pattern.length() - nth_difference)){
                matchedWords.add(input);
        }
        if((input.length() - pattern.length() == 1) && (matchCounter >= input.length() - nth_difference)){
            matchedWords.add(input);
        }
   }
    return matchedWords;
}


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int nth_difference = 1;
    String pattern = "mert";
    String[] data = new String[]{"aert", "ert", "meat", "mmert", "merst", "merts","meritos"};
    System.out.println(getNthDifferenceWords(pattern,data,nth_difference));

    nth_difference = 2;
    pattern = "merit";
    data = new String[]{"aert", "ert", "meat", "mmert", "merst", "merts","demerit","merito", "meritos"};
    System.out.println(getNthDifferenceWords(pattern,data,nth_difference));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a 1-letter difference, pre-build a table in the following way.  Build a 2-column lexicon with the 'word' in the second column, and the following in the first column:  One position at a time, remove one letter from the word.

Example:  "meat" is the word; here are the rows for it in the table:

```
`col1` `col2`
------ ------
meat   meat
eat    meat
mat    meat
met    meat
mea    meat
```

For "meet" (note the dup letter):

```
meet   meet
eet    meet
met    meet  -- only needed once
mee    meet
```

Then test in a similar way.  When searching for "mert", do

```
WHERE col1 IN ('mert', 'ert', 'mrt', 'met', 'ert')
```

Note that you will get both "meat" and "meet" from the above example.  Note also what will happen with "met" and "meets".

And, it checks for simple transpositions.  Searching for "meta":

```
WHERE col1 IN ('meta', 'eta', 'mta', 'mea', 'met')
```

will find "meat", "meet" (and other words like met, mean, ...)  Arguably, "meta" -> "mean" is a 2-letter distance, but oh well.

Checking your test cases-- mert vs

aert  -- via "ert"
ert   -- via "ert"
meat  -- via "met"
mmert -- via "mert"
merst -- via "mert"
merts -- via "mert"

Meanwhile, have `PRIMARY KEY(col1, col2), INDEX(col2)` on that table.